# Why this code don't work correctly in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

3 days ago a friend give me a code to keep some sentences and delete other sentences that they were not need in notepad ++. Today My teacher told me that this code don't work for all of sentences and it cleans most of the tags that we need. please help me and correct this code. 
It's s important for me to present my Corpus for tomorrow.please.

I want to find some special strings in my text and then delete other strings.

For example in this sentence:

```
( (IP-MAT (CONJ vnnd)
      (NP-NOM (D das) (N wort))
      (BED war)
      (PP (P bey)
          (CODE [2])
          (NP-DAT (NPR Gott)))
      (. ,))
```

I want to regularly keep: `CONJ D N BED P NPR`. 
and delete other strings in this text.

Second example:

```
( (IP-MAT-SPE (NP-NOM-LFD (D diser) (NPR Jhesus)
 (, ,)
 (CP-REL-SPE (WNP-1 (WPRO wilcher)) (C 0)
 (IP-SUB-SPE (NP-NOM T-1) (PP (P von) (NP-DAT (PRO euch))) (BEPI ist) (RP auff) (VAN genomen) (PP (P gen) 
 (NP-ACC-XXX (NPR hymel)))))) 
 (, ,) 
 (NP-NOM-RSP (D der)) (RDPI wirt) (VB komen)
(PP (P wie) (CP-ADV-SPE (C 0) (IP-SUB-SPE (NP-NOM (PRO yhr)) (NP-ACC-2 (PRO yhn)) (VBN gesehen) (HVPI habt) 
(IP-INF-SPE (NP-ACC-SBJ ICH-2) (PP (P gen)
(NP-ACC-XXX (NPR hymel))) (VB faren)))))
 (. .))
```

and I want to change them to this :

```
D NPR , WPRO C NP-NOM P PRO BEPI RP VAN P NPR , D RDPI VB , P C PRO PRO VBN HVPI NP-ACC-SBJ P NPR VB . –
```

and that code is:
Find:

```
(?:(?!\n\n).(?<!\n\n))*?\(([\w,.-]+)\s+[\w,.-]+\)+|(?:(?!\n\n).(?<!\n\n))+$
```

Replace with:

```
$1
```

[Dollar, then "1", then space]

**But it don't work for the sentences like:**

```
 (IP-MAT (CODE [4])
        (CONJ vnd)
      (NP-NOM *con*) 
      (RDD wurden)
      (Q alle) 
      (ADJP (ADJ voll)
        (NP-GEN (D des)
            (ADJ heyligen)
            (NPR geysts)))
      (. ,)) (ID SEPTEMBERTESTAMENT-ACTS,.45))
```

it must be shown: CONJ NP-NOM RDD Q ADJP D ADJ D ADJ NPR .

**or don't work in this code:**

```
( (IP-MAT (CODE [7])
      (NP-NOM (PRO sie))
      (VBD entsatzten)
      (NP-ACC-RFL (PRO sich))
      (ADVP (ADV aber))
      (Q alle)
      (. ,)
      (IP-MAT (NP-NOM *con*) 
          (VBD verwunderten)
          (NP-ACC-RFL (PRO sich)))
      (IP-MAT (CONJ vnnd)
          (NP-NOM *con*) 
          (VBD sprachen)
          (PP (P+D+ADJ vnternander))
          (, ,)
```

It must be shown: NP-NOM VBD PRO ADV Q .
NP-NOM VBD PRO CONJ NP-NOM VBD P+D+ADJ ,

**or about this example :**

```
 (IP-MAT-SPE (CODE [8]) 
          (CP-QUE-SPE (WADVP (WADV wie))
              (IP-SUB-SPE (VBPI horen)
                      (NP-NOM (PRO wyr)
                          (NP-NOM-PRN *ICH*-1))
                      (ADVP (ADV denn))
                      (, ,)
                      (NP-NOM-PRN-1 (D eyn) (ADJ iglicher))
                      (NP-ACC (PRO$ seyne) (N sprach)
                          (, ,)
                          (CP-REL-SPE (WPP-2 (WADV $dar) (P $ynnen))
                              (C 0) 
                              (IP-SUB-SPE (PP *T*-2)
                                      (CODE {TEXT:darynnen})
                                      (NP-NOM (PRO wyr))
                                      (VAN geporn)
                                      (BEPI sind))))))
          (. ?)) (ID SEPTEMBERTESTAMENT-ACTS,.52))
```

it must be shown: WADV VBPI PRO NP-NOM-PRN ADV , D ADJ POR$ N , WADV P C PP PRO VAN BEPI .

that code unfortunately delete PRO$ or NP-NOM or PP or Q+N etc.

Excuse me that  I can't edit this post. I hope my codes will be appear to all.
If they weren't I can upload the Corpus text file.

Comment: @nixda  help me please nixda.  isn't there any one to help me?? :((

Comment: Oh..I can't believe there is no person in this world  that help me not to lose my job because of this code. please help me it is so important for me

Comment: This is better on StackOverflow.  Do not repost as this will likely be migrated soon,

Comment: @Dave M what? I know nothing because of stress now!:((

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep special strings in notepad++ and delete other strings?](http://superuser.com/questions/653417/how-to-keep-special-strings-in-notepad-and-delete-other-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Well, taking the previous regex:

```
(?:(?!\n\n).(?<!\n\n))*?\(([\w,.-]+)\s+[\w,.-]+\)+|(?:(?!\n\n).(?<!\n\n))+$
```

You can add characters to the available character classes as indicated:

```
(?:(?!\n\n).(?<!\n\n))*?\(([\w,.-]+)\s+[\w,.-]+\)+|(?:(?!\n\n).(?<!\n\n))+$
                           ^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^
```

Change the second and/or first to include more characters, for instance, using `[\w,.$-]` will allow `PRO$` to be kept. Just make sure that you insert the extra character(s) before the last hyphen or the regex will break.

See:

```
(?:(?!\n\n).(?<!\n\n))*?\(([$\w,.+-]+)\s+[$\w,.*?-]+\)+|(?:(?!\n\n).(?<!\n\n))+$
```

I added some more characters, but there are things I think that aren't regular, or maybe you did some typos, like `ID` which you didn't mention in your question.

Remember the regex demo site I linked you to last time? [See it again](http://regex101.com/r/iX4aP5) for these samples. You can play around with it; and note that the blue part are deleted while the green part are being kept after you do the replace.

Comment: @user259288 Hopefully, you won't have to wait a lot next time, I told you how to modify the expression as needed, but like mentioned, it might not work for all the cases you have, since there seems to be some funky anomalies in the pattern. Those, I guess, you can tackle them manually if there aren't a lot.

Comment: Jerry very very very thank you for answering. Do you believe I'm crying now because of this answer?!! It's seems correct. thank you. I'll check it again now.But I think it is correct. Thank you again my friend.

Comment: working manually is so hard and wast time. it is 5 hour I was working but I can separate only 500 sentence!!! and my program has 120000 sentence. But this code will help me. if it was not work, i can check manually easily.

Comment: thank you. I never forget an unknown friend who helped me. :)

Comment: @user259288 Funny, I have used 'unknown' as part of my username in many sites and even here before I changed to 'Jerry' xP

Comment: @Oh my God..really funny. :)Being unknown is always good.you don't know me but helped me a lot and i don't know you but you became my first friend in this site. :) You recall me I must choose a name in this site. /have a good night.